# How to port forms from 2017.1 to 2017.2 ( cluttered fields )

Tags: orbeon

The form in 2017.1  looks OK:
[image]
When I use the formrunner home to push the published form to 2017.2.1, the form also looks OK:
[image]
When I took the source from 2017.1 and insert it in the 2017.2.1 formbuilder,
the form in the formbuilder also looks OK:
[image]
But using the test key to preview the form, the fields are cluttered. Also if I publish the form and look at the published form.
[image]

[Link to the used xhtml source code in orbeon 2017.1](https://gist.github.com/hoila/f98d11fa3f3138d8e015d583f345718c)

What is the right way to port  forms from 2017.1 to 2017.2.1?
Many thanks for every guide and hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do reproduce the issue. The problem is that with Orbeon Forms 2017.2, Orbeon Forms switched the way it represents grids. Grids now always have 12 columns. This means that grids previously created with 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or even 12 columns adjust perfectly.

But grids with 5 columns, like your second grid, are just handled as having 5 rows in a 12-column grid, and so they don't look like before.

A workaround is to make the grid have 6 or 4 columns (`<xh:td>`) in the source instead.

Comment: Many thanks for your guidance!  Now the form is OK also in 2017.2.1